# How to make a contour smooth in OpenCV

Tags: python, image-processing

I am using OpenCV(4.5.1) and trying to extract a smooth contour of an object on my image.
Firstly I got the contour by:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

I got the following contour:

[image: I got the following image]

Then I tried to remove the redundant element on the image by:

```
for i,cnt in enumerate(contours):
    # if the contour has no other contours inside of it
    if hierarchy[0][i][2] == -1 :
        # if the size of the contour is greater than a threshold
          
            if  cv2.contourArea(cnt) >  500:
                    print(cv2.moments(cnt))
                    epsilon = 0.0001*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
                    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)
                    cv2.drawContours(mask3,[approx], 0, (255), 1)
```

And I got the following contour:

[image]

How can I go further and remove more rough edges and redundant details of my contour?
In other words, I just want straight lines and smooth curves on my image, what can I do?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try instead to simplify the gray-scale image before extracting the contours. Contours are hard to work with. Any non-linear edge-preserving smoothing would work. Look into bilateral filters, morphological filters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify the gray-scale image before extracting the contours.
This will remove faint edges. You should use edge preserving filters like the bilateral filter or median filter.